# Project.exe System Warning : Unknown Hard Error after adding user control WPF in winforms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, debugging, visual-studio-2019

My main app is developped with Winforms (.NET Framework 4.7.2, updgraded from 3.5)

I want to host a WPF form inside this main app (using element host).
After adding the `UserControl1.xaml` (ie the WPF form), when I Start debbuging in Visual Studio 2019, I randomly have a

> System Warning : Unknown Hard Error

(but the app in debug mode is still working)

This happens only in debug mode, if I use the app without visual studio it's not showing this working.

There is just a grid inside my WPF form (`UserControl1.xaml`).
The problem still occurs if I link the WPF form to an element host inside the main winforms apps.

Thanks for help

Comment: This is a Windows error that has nothing to do with C# or WPF. It's typically caused by corrupted system files or registry entries. Unless it's *your* app that corrupted those files. Does your program modify the registry, or try to write to `Program Files` or `Windows` ? Or perhaps your system already has corrupted files?

Comment: I remember that after quitting the debug mode I sometimes had randomly several Unhandled exceptions in my closing event without triggering the catch{} that could corrupt the system. (only in debug mode). I was thinking this could be because of the multiple thread running and not closing properly, but I fix this and sometimes these closing exception still occurs. Otherwise I'm not modifying the registers with my app or trying to write to Program Files or Windows. The Unknown Hard Error is dissapearing if I remove the usercontrol1.xaml

Comment: In any case, check Windows' Event Viewer, in the Application or System log. Application crashes are always logged there. System-level problems are logged in the `System` log. Can you find any errors there? And post your code

Comment: The exceptions at the closing event where in that line 
Environment.Exit(0);, so I surround this line with a try catch(SystemException ex), but the exception still randomly  occurs on that line without triggering the catch. It's a bit hard to pinpoint which part of the code is causing the problems, that's why I haven't posted any code, I thought this may be a config problem. I also check the Windows Event Viewer but I could not pinpoint which error are linked to my app (but I'll keep this open, did'nt know about this feature). Thanks for the help

Comment: `Exit(0)`? You're *asking* the application to terminate abnormally. You still haven't posted any code. Applications exit normally by closing the main form, or exiting their `Main` method. Why did you use `Exit(0)` in the first place?

Comment: BTW, [Exit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=netframework-4.8)'s behavior is explained in the method's docs. It terminates immediately, doesn't even call `finally`, can't be aborted.

Comment: I also had a quit button so I used 'Exit(0)'. Other ways of closing where not quitting the thread (for example a bluetooth thread). Also which part of the code do you want me to post ?